# Migrating DNS Server -- Record data still shows name of previous server

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, migration, dns-zone

I have been tasked with Migrating a DNS Server.

- Two separate servers
- There is no Active Directory
- Actual Migration -- not just creating secondary zones

---

For the sake of example let's name the servers:

SERVER1

- Windows Server 2003
- 10.10.10.1
- Migrating from

SERVER2

- Windows Server 2008
- 10.10.10.2
- Migrating To

---

I followed various tutorials including:

1. [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVPCdUsz90g)
2. [Web Page](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/how-to-migrate-dns-information-to-windows-server-2008/)

---

**Steps Taken**

1. Set up DNS on 10.10.10.2
2. Created new secondary zones on 10.10.10.2 to reflect primary zones from 10.10.10.1
3. Allow zone transfers from 10.10.10.1 to 10.10.10.2
4. Transfer records from 10.10.10.1 to 10.10.10.2
5. Switch zones on 10.10.10.2 from secondary to primary

I do not want to shut down / remove SERVER1 until I know this is done right.

---

## PROBLEM

Okay, so all the records are there and all is well...

HOWEVER!!! Some of the data sections (SOA, NS) in the new records of SERVER2 start with the text 'serverone'

EXAMPLE of SERVER2 Records

........... NAME ................................ TYPE ...................................... DATA

(same as parent folder) ........... Start of Authority ............. serverone.redbluegreen....

Why does it still say serverone? Server1 is going to be shut down and removed as a DNS server. So am I correct in assuming that is incorrect and needs to be fixed?

Comment: I haven't seen that particular behavior. Have you refreshed or reloaded the zone after changing it to a primary zone?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes I have. I was thinking that it could have something to do with  dynamic updates? Or that could be something different.

Answer (score 0):

A zone transfer transfers an exact copy of the DNS zone data to a secondary name server, of course you'll find resource records still referencing the original primary there.

You'll need to convert that zone to a primary zone.

> To change the zone type using the Windows interface
>   Open DNS Manager.
>
> 1. In the console tree, right-click the applicable zone, and then select Properties.
> 2. On the General tab, note the current zone type, and then click Change.
> 3. In Change Zone Type, select the zone type **primary** instead of the current zone type **secondary** and then click **OK**.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771150(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: I've already converted the secondary zones to primary zones. However the SOA and NS records still start with 'serverone'.